# Using jquery and a button to load a div with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, css, html, button

I have a js that loads dynamic content from a database and shows the var's in a `li` element:

```
$("<li id='l_"+marker['__gm_id']+"' class='clinic_list' />")
.html("<div><strong>"+v.name+"</strong></div> etc...")
.click(function() {
    //displayPoint(marker, i);
    infowindow.setContent(null);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    toggleBounce(marker); })
.appendTo("#list");
```

Now I want to add a button into the `li` element that opens a div with dynamic content. The button looks likt this:

```
<button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-1">open dynamic div</button>
```

And the button should open this div (modal dialog by css3):

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
        <div>
            <p>"+v.name+"</p>

            <button class="md-close">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The frontend: http://www.ihrvorteilsclub.de/home/iv/search/search.php

The rest of the js: http://www.ihrvorteilsclub.de/home/iv/search/js/super-store-finder-mobile.js

But it does not work. I don't know how to combine this. When I add the button and try top open the div, nothing happens. Can anybody help me and show me how to do that!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is your Javascript that opens the modal, and where do you attach that function to the button's `click` event? The JS that you posted at the top does neither.

Comment: @George Cummins <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/modalEffects.js"></script>
<script src="js/cssParser.js"></script>
<script src="js/css-filters-polyfill.js"></script>